# Stop grep after matching pattern, not entire line? Files with long line / single line

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching

I am using grep to return only the string between a pattern (-o), within a number of files, eg

```
grep -i -r -o 'Rows="[^#][^"]*"' *
```

I would like it to stop after the first matching pattern, I tried grep -m NUM / --max-count=NUM
but this stops reading the file after the NUM matching *lines*, not the pattern, and unfortunately, all the files in this folder are one long line.

Can grep stop after the first matched pattern, alternatively should I be doing this with something else?

*Bonus question   -  Being able to output it as "Matched Pattern" 'Filename' so I can sort it?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to do this in `grep`.  In fact, most Unix utilities are stubbornly line-based.  I don't think there's a way to print out only part of a line in `sed`, for instance.  Even in `awk`, there's probably a way to cobble something together, but my guess is that it would be unsatisfying.

If you have GNU awk on your system, though, try this:

```
gawk 'BEGIN {RS="pattern"} {print RT, FILENAME; exit}' filename
```

`RS` sets the record separator (usually the newline) to be the pattern.  `RT` is the text matched by `RS`.  `FILENAME` is self-explanatory.  `exit` stops execution.  So, after the first record, `awk` will print the pattern text and filename, and exit.  This won't work with more than one file, because the exit here is unconditional.

If you need to run this on all the files in a directory structure, use `find` and `xargs`, and don't exit unless you've found something:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 gawk 'BEGIN {RS="pattern"} {print RT, FILENAME; if (RT != "") exit}'
```

This prints out the filenames (preceded by a space) of everything without the pattern, but prints out the pattern and filename when it hits the first pattern, then stops.

Of course, you need to be a little careful with this command: since the record separator may not be there at all, `gawk` may slurp the entire contents of a file into its buffer, and it may run out of memory.  (When I tested this on my system I got a failure at 490 MB.)

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas come to mind;

```
perl -nle '/(Rows="[^#][^"]*")/ or continue; print $ARGV, ":", $1; exit 0' files ...
```

This will, however, read the entire line before processing it. The other idea is to preprocess the file before passing it to grep, something like this hack, maybe:

```
for file in *; do
    # Replace every R with newline,
    # and every newline with dot.
    # Your tr's syntax for newline may be different
    tr 'R\n' '\n.'  < "$file" |
    sed -n '/^\(ows="[^#][^"]*"\).*/{;s%%'"$file:"'R\1%;p;q;}'
done
```

Your tr and sed might be different from mine, so this could require some adaptation.

Edit: added loop, replace grep with sed.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't test it, but I'd try:

```
find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r cat | grep -m 1 -i -o 'Rows="[^#][^"]*"'
```

Comment: I don't think this is better than the suggestion in the question.  The `find|cat` combination does what grep does.

Comment: @JXG: But at least it closes the pipe after the first match. So depending on scheduling not all files might be opened and the command exits earlier than the original proposal.